# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actula type was the promise

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i'm facing the that error. im building the simple crud operation by using the react and react-redux. i'm using the readux thunk my app is still working properly but i have clear myself about that error in console this error is coming when i update data or delete then i come in my console

Below is my action component

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

    dispatch({ type: CREATE, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

export const updatePost = (id, post) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.updatePost(id, post);

    dispatch({ type: UPDATE, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

there is my reducer which is used to dispatch my data

```
const posts = (posts = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE:
      return posts.filter((post)=>post._id !== action.payload );
    case UPDATE:
    return posts.map((post)=>post._id===action.payload._id?action.payload:post) 
     case LIKE:
     return posts.map((post)=>post._id===action.payload._id?action.payload:post) 
    
  };

  export default posts
```

Here is my index.js

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>

    <App />

  </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Make sure that the payload you are sending in dispatch have _id field because you are comparing it in actions.

Comment: is i add the _id field in the   ()=> async (dispatch )

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying. Can you please attach here the payload object you are sending in dispatch